# How to fix Zend DbTableGateway read/destroy infinite loop after session expiration?

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

I have a Zend\Session Manager with a DbTableGateway to handle sessions. My code is in [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38357149/2037065). But whenever the session expires, I get an error `Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in [path]\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Sql\AbstractExpression.php on line 40`

I found out how to change the xdebug nesting level to 200, but then I reached the 200 limit too.

[image: Picture of the fatal error.]

So I have an infinite loop between DbTableGateway->read() and DbTableGateway->destroy(). I noticed the 2 lines referenced in the error each call the other method, but it's Zend code so I don't want to change it.

It only happens after the session expires, and not when I remove the row containing the session information from the database. When I looked at the table after this occurred, I noticed that the row is still present in the table except for the data column.

```
id              name            modified    lifetime data
[random string] [session name]  1468587768  1440     -
```

So it looks like the read() method checks the table for a row containing the id and name, and finds this row, then calls destroy(), which calls read(). How can I fix this?

On a side note, refreshing the page solves the problem for the user, but I don't want to have code that throws an exception at the user and forces them to refresh the page.

Comment: You need investigate data that set to a method `destroy` and try to remove row from database manually with this data

Comment: I didn't get all that, but I investigated the read and destroy method and confirmed that indeed the first thing destroy() does is call read(), and then read() checks if the row is in the database, and because it is, it checks if the row is past its expired time, and because it is, it calls destroy(), initiating the loop. This problem persists until a new session (with a new ID) is started, but the offending row is never removed from the database. I can remove them manually while testing, but that's not an option for a finished product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me: create a class that extends DbTableGateway and modify its destroy method to check if a row exists rather than call the read() function. Then use that class instead of DbTableGateway.

So here's the code for the new save handler class:

```
class MySessionSaveHandler extends DbTableGateway
{
    /**
     * Destroy session
     *
     * @param  string $id
     * @return bool
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        // I removed "read" to prevent an infinite loop, and am using the first line of "read" instead to check if the row exists
        $rows = $this->tableGateway->select([
            $this->options->getIdColumn()   => $id,
            $this->options->getNameColumn() => $this->sessionName,
        ]);

        if (! (bool) $rows) {
            return true;
        }

        return (bool) $this->tableGateway->delete([
            $this->options->getIdColumn()   => $id,
            $this->options->getNameColumn() => $this->sessionName,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And here's how you replace DbTableGateway:

```
/* @var $adapter \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter */
$adapter = $serviceManager->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$tableGateway = new TableGateway('mytablename', $adapter);
return new MySessionSaveHandler($tableGateway, new DbTableGatewayOptions());
```